# Dotnetnuke , "web.Config Registration missing"

Tags: web-config, dotnetnuke, registration

I am using Dotnetnuke, when I edit contents of main Portal its Ok,

but, when I want to edit contents of Child Portal (RADEditor) I recieve following bug. !

Error: " Web.config registration missing".

I check it , there is Httphandler registration in Web.config.

how can I solve it , any one can help?!

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Check to see you don't have an extra web.config sitting in the child root folder of the child portal.